# Realm - database isn't up to date after a delete

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've got some objects in my Realm database. I need to delete an object from it.
When I delete my object from my `Realm()` instance, **the objects are well deleted**.

But after performing the delete request, I need to retrieve all objects from the database, but here surprise, **the object is still here**.

I think I have a thread problem, or something like that. 
I don't know where to investigate.

**My simplified code :**

*My delete method :*

```
func myDeleteFunc(completion : ()->Void){
     let realm = try! Realm()
     // ...
     try! realm.write {
         realm.delete(myObject)
     }
     completion()
}
// Here the object have been deleted from the realm instance, no problem
```

This method is called from a viewController where I execute the completion block. 
This completion block **contains the request that retrieve all objects** from my Realm database :

*The viewController that executes the method and the completion block :*

```
 myDeleteFunc(completion: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let realm = try! Realm()                  
        let objects = Array(realm.objects(MyObject.self).sorted(byProperty: "aProperty"))
        // Here objects still contains the object that I have already deleted
        // ...
    }
}
```

I think my 2 `realm` instances differs, or have problems between threads because I have a `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT :**

I noticed that when I check with breakpoints, sometimes it works.

So maybe that the delete request have not been committed yet, and that I retrieve the objects before the end of the delete request ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you put the `async` block in an autorelease pool:

```
 myDeleteFunc(completion: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let realm = try! Realm()                  
        let objects = Array(realm.objects(MyObject.self).sorted(byProperty: "aProperty"))
        // Here objects still contains the object that I have already deleted
        // ...
    }
}
```

Should be

```
 myDeleteFunc(completion: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        autoreleasepool {
            let realm = try! Realm()                  
            let objects = Array(realm.objects(MyObject.self).sorted(byProperty: "aProperty"))
            // Here objects still contains the object that I have already deleted
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you do this `autoreleasepool { ... }` wrap for any background thread where you create a Realm instance, primarily in the GCD.

---

If that **still** doesn't work, you can do:

```
 myDeleteFunc(completion: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        autoreleasepool {
            let realm = try! Realm()                  
            realm.refresh()
```

Comment: It works with autoreleasepool and the realm.refresh(), thank you but why have I to do this ?

Comment: Well technically the `refresh()` part is more of a workaround if it still doesn't work, although that means you still have open Realm instances that you should be wrapping with `autoreleasepool` block to ensure you close them.

Comment: Using an `autoreleasepool` will only work by accident, if at all. It would just prevent an existing Realm instance for that thread from sticking around. The `refresh()` part isn't actually a workaround, but rather the solution, by design. It's the right way to advance/refresh a Realm to reflect the latest state from all other transactions on other threads. See my answer for more.

Comment: @jpsim `It would just prevent an existing Realm instance for that thread from sticking around.` that is my intention.

Comment: In most cases that won't be possible on the main thread if the Realm is ever accessed in view controller properties, or anywhere outside of an explicit `autoreleasepool`, which is highly likely in the vast majority of apps.

Comment: @jpsim well, auto-release-pools make sense primarily for non-looping background threads :p

Comment: @jpsim I'm primarily basing this answer on the fact that Realm-Java does **not** have an explicit `refresh()` method, and relies on closing the Realm instances on the given thread.

Answer (score 2):

Realm isolates transactions on each thread to avoid changes from one thread immediately affect another. This mechanism also avoids the "faults" inherent to ORMs.

In your code, you can choose to refresh (advance) the realm to the latest state at points that you control and can handle data before and after the refresh being different.

Realms on a thread with a runloop (such as the main thread) auto-advance on every iteration of the runloop by default.

In your code sample, you invoke `DispatchQueue.main.async` immediately after a commit from another thread, which means that if you already have a Realm on the main thread, the async block will be at the same state and won't include the last commit.

But you can call `Realm.refresh()` explicitly at the start of your async block, which will ensure that this block sees that last commit:

```
myDeleteFunc(completion: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let realm = try! Realm()                  
        realm.refresh()
        let objects = Array(realm.objects(MyObject.self).sorted(byProperty: "aProperty"))
        // ...
    }
}
```

See Realm's docs on [Seeing Changes From Other Threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#seeing-changes-from-other-threads) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this is more clear. 

Last question : In fact in my delete method, I'm performing multiple deletion queries in a for-loop on the Realm instance.

So based on what you said, if the two threads can be executed at the same time, I conclude that the 2 Realm instances in my code can differ even if I do a refresh, no ? 

Because yes, the Realm will be refreshed with the last commit. But after the refresh, maybe that some delete queries are still pending to be committed no?